# How to add a extra route in a Sinatra project?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How can I `prepend` a extra route in Sinatra class of another gem?

**How I'm tring**

```
module StealthWebhook
  module Route
    post '/api/v1/webhook' do
      response_status, response_body = Webhook.send_request(request)

      status response_status
      body response_body
    end
  end
end


module Stealth
  class Server < Sinatra::Base
    prepend StealthWebhook::Route
  end
end
```

I need add this route in [this class](https://github.com/hellostealth/stealth/blob/master/lib/stealth/server.rb)

but I receive this error:

```
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/usr/local/bundle/bin/puma)
bot_1       | NoMethodError: undefined method `post' for StealthWebhook::Route:Module
bot_1       |   /bot/lib/stealth-webhook/lib/stealth-webhook/route.rb:6:in `<module:Route>'
bot_1       |   /bot/lib/stealth-webhook/lib/stealth-webhook/route.rb:4:in `<module:StealthWebhook>'
bot_1       |   /bot/lib/stealth-webhook/lib/stealth-webhook/route.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
bot_1       |   /bot/lib/stealth-webhook/lib/stealth-webhook/base.rb:5:in `require_relative'
bot_1       |   /bot/lib/stealth-webhook/lib/stealth-webhook/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
bot_1       |   /bot/lib/stealth-webhook/lib/stealth-webhook.rb:1:in `require_relative'
bot_1       |   /bot/lib/stealth-webhook/lib/stealth-webhook.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
bot_1       |   /bot/lib/aggregator.rb:5:in `require_relative'
bot_1       |   /bot/lib/aggregator.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
bot_1       |   /bot/config/initializers/overridings.rb:1:in `require_relative'
bot_1       |   /bot/config/initializers/overridings.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/stealth-1.0.4/lib/stealth/base.rb:85:in `require_relative'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/stealth-1.0.4/lib/stealth/base.rb:85:in `block in require_directory'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/stealth-1.0.4/lib/stealth/base.rb:93:in `each'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/stealth-1.0.4/lib/stealth/base.rb:93:in `for_each_file_in'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/stealth-1.0.4/lib/stealth/base.rb:85:in `require_directory'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/stealth-1.0.4/lib/stealth/base.rb:66:in `load_environment'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/stealth-1.0.4/lib/stealth/base.rb:33:in `boot'
bot_1       |   /bot/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
bot_1       |   config.ru:2:in `require_relative'
bot_1       |   config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
bot_1       |   config.ru:in `new'
bot_1       |   config.ru:in `<main>'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:318:in `load_rackup'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:243:in `app'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:145:in `load_and_bind'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/single.rb:96:in `run'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:184:in `run'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:78:in `run'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/bin/puma:29:in `load'
bot_1       |   /usr/local/bundle/bin/puma:29:in `<top (required)>'
```

**EDIT:**

I solved using `Stealth::Server.post`. This is the best way?

```
module StealthWebhook
  module Route
    Stealth::Server.post '/api/v1/webhook' do
      response_status, response_body = Webhook.send_request(request)

      status response_status
      body response_body
    end
  end
end


module Stealth
  class Server < Sinatra::Base
    prepend StealthWebhook::Route
  end
end
```

Comment: You've not loaded the DSL (domain-specific language) for Sinatra, which defines the `post` method: `require 'sinatra'`

Comment: @Cam Still show me same error =(